# I need to create a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array in Laravel 5.8 but I can't  seem to get it to work.

It's running on PHP 7.3 and Laravel 5.8.
Here's what I've already try:

```
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $email_data = array($address => array($location));
}
    $arr = array($email_data[count($email_data)-1] => $address);

for ($i=count($email_data) - 2 ; $i>=0 ; $i--) {
    $arr = array($email_data[$i] => $arr);
}

foreach ($ageMatches as $ageMatch) {
    $age['Age'] = $ageMatch[1];
    array_push($arr, $age);
}
```

Here's the data I'm using:

```
        ELY FARM
      THE ADDRESS
  BW8010 2.55  UNIT 1

Logged   03 JUN 19 23:59

     SUMMARY REPORT

----UNIT 1  PERCH 1-----
     House 1, Pen 1

Age         DAYS       7
Total               3997
Average     GMS       64
Deviation   GMS       14
Evenness    %         29
C.V.        %       21.9
Daily gain  GMS        9

----UNIT 1  PERCH 2-----
     House 1, Pen 2

Age         DAYS       7
Total               3849
Average     GMS       73
Deviation   GMS       17
Evenness    %         29
C.V.        %       23.3
Daily gain  GMS        9
```

So I want to to be like:

```
array(
"Ely Farm" => array(
    "Unit 1 Perch 1" => array( 
        "Age" => 7,
        "Total" => 3849,
    ),
    "Unit 1 Perch 2" => array(
        "Age" => 7,
    )
),
"Next Location" => array(
    array(
    ),
);
```

At the moment I have the following and I can't work where I'm going wrong (if I dump `$location[1]` it does come out with the location instead of hyphens but when I don't dump it comes out as below).

```
array:1 [▼
  "Ely Farm" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "------------------------"
      1 => "---------------"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: what kind of variable type is the data are you using ?

Comment: _“Here's the data I'm using:”_ - that makes little sense, in combination with the code you have shown. If there’s an additional step of parsing this involved somehow, then you should either show us that, or (preferably) the data structure that results in after parsing.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using regex to pull the information out. So the actual data coming out are arrays for example: `[0 => 7, 1 => 7]` for the Age and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block you are rewriting `$email_data` each iteration

```
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $email_data = array($address => array($location));
}
```

What you should do instead is

```
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $email_data[] = array($address => array($location));
}
```

This will continuously add the values instead of replacing them. You have the same issue below too with `$arr`